# Remove Top and Bottom Space on small devices

Tags: css

working on a simple slideshow (which needs to use css transparent background instead of images) but I can't for the life of me get rid of the whitespace top and bottom when browser is resized or view on portrait mobile devices. I know it's probably really simple but I'd love your help:

```
    <style>
    
    
    #fred {
        top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    overflow: hidden;
    }   
    
    .slideshow-container {
        top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    overflow: hidden;
        
        
    }

.seats {
    margin: -400px 0;
    padding: 0px 0;
   max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
    height: 600px;
    top 0px;
}

.roomx1 {
  background: transparent url("roomx1.png")50% 50% no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
    background-size: contain;
}


.roomx2 {
  background: transparent url("roomx2.png")50% 50% no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
    background-size: contain;
}


/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
    z-index: 100;
  
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */


/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade2 {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade2 {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade2 {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
    
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-12>">
<div id="fred">
<div class="slideshow-container">

<div class="mySlides fade2">
  
    <div class="seats">
  <div class="roomx1"></div>
        </div>
 
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade2">
  <div class="seats">
  <div class="roomx2"></div>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="mySlides fade2">
  <div class="seats">
  <div class="roomx1"></div>
        </div>
</div>

<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
        </div>
            </div>
    </div>
<br>



<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I've put all on the code on one page for ease of testing. Would love to know your thoughts

Comment: It would be easier to see what's going on if you made this page simpler! If this was my code I would try to isolate the code to find the problem. Right now this code doesn't even work (I just put it into jsfiddle)

Comment: Please give more information. For example the HTML-Code and what you tried. Maybe a screenshot of the problem. Right now I don't understand if this only a problem on mobile devices.